# Fitnesse set proxy for Chrome browser

Tags: proxy, fitnesse

I need to set proxy for Chrome browser in Fitnesse , so that the browser can open certain websites.

Is it possible to add it while initialising the selenium grid in Fitnesse ?

And also is it possible to add username and password to it ?

Adding Fitnesse code below : I am using a selenium hub

```
|Import                           |
|nl.hsac.fitnesse.fixture.slim.web|

!define GRID_HUB {http://remote-selenium.local:4444/wd/hub}

|script               |selenium driver setup                                                                                       |
|connect to driver at |${GRID_HUB}          |with capabilities|!{browserName:chrome}  |
```

I need to pass the proxy object to this. How can I do that ?

A similar code in Java would be :

```java
String nodeUrl = "http://remote-selenium.local:4444/wd/hub";

Proxy proxy = new Proxy();

proxy.setHttpProxy("proxy:8080");
proxy.setSslProxy("proxy:8080");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.setCapability("proxy",proxy);

RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl),options);
```

How can I achieve this in Fitnesse ?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Which fixtures are you using to control Selenium? Did you write your own, which language do you use?

Comment: @FriedHoeben : I have updated the question with the code .

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I never had to work with proxies, but some googling suggests that you should also be able to configure the proxy using the generic `chrome.switches` capability which passes them as command line options. Those options are described at: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-settings

So that would give you something like:

```
|script              |map fixture                                                                             |
|set value           |chrome                                                           |for|browserName       |
|set value           |--proxy-server="http=http://proxy:8080/;https=http://proxy:8080/"|for|chrome.switches[0]|
|$chromeCapabilities=|copy map                                                                                |


!define GRID_HUB {http://remote-selenium.local:4444/wd/hub}

|script              |selenium driver setup                            |
|connect to driver at|${GRID_HUB}|with capabilities|$chromeCapabilities|
```

You could add more elements by adding lines setting values for  `chrome.switches[1]`, `chrome.switches[2]`, etc.

So for instance:

```
|set value  |--proxy-bypass-list="*.google.com;127.0.0.1:8080"|for|chrome.switches[1]|
```

To not proxy requests to any google.com subdomain or requests to 127.0.0.1 port 8080.

When not using a remote chrome (e.g. starting chrome using `|start driver for|chrome|`) you can pass command line arguments as profile. This should also allow for proxy settings. See for instance [hsac-fitnesse-fixture's BrowserTest.SuiteSetUp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/master/wiki/FitNesseRoot/HsacAcceptanceTests/SlimTests/BrowserTest/SuiteSetUp.wiki) that passes command line options to make Chrome run in headless mode.